# Cron job command in linux hosting

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have linux hosting on godaddy and I m trying to execute php file through cron command. But its not working. Can anyone help me out from this ? Thanks in advance.

Cron Command Code :

/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/folder/file.php

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the cron deamon is running and the correct user is running it. You can try:**

```
systemctl status crond.service
```

**If it's not running, start it:**

```
systemctl start crond.service
```

**Make sure the deamon starts on reboot:**

```
systemctl enable crond.service
```

**Make sure your path to PHP is correct. Check the path:**

```
whereis php
```

**Your cron command looks incomplete (missing the run intervals). Like so:**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/user/folder/file.php
```

**Those asteriks denote the run intervals. Use a tool to help you determine the proper run intervals. Like this one:**

https://crontab.guru/

**Run crontab under the correct user and edit the cron command. For example, here we'll edit the crontab for apache:**

```
crontab -u apache -e
```

**Hope that helps!**